# JButton switching styles between computers

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton

At school the `JButton` is themed like this:

### [image: School]

At home the `JButton` is themed like this:

[image: Home]

Is it possible to switch the style to the second image? 
Not really that big of a deal, but I'd rather have it show up as the second one.
Both computers use Windows 7, if I were to create a button from my home computer, it would look like the second one, but If I make it at school and switch it to my computer at home, it would look like the first

Why does it switch between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

The first is using the Metal look and feel and can be initialised using something like..

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
```

or

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
```